# Best way to send valuable item back home while travelling (Istanbul)?

Tags: turkey, istanbul, shipping, mail

I'm in Istanbul for a couple months and my phone is broken but it's still under warranty. I would like to send my phone back home to get it fixed but as I don't speak Turkish and I find it's quite hard to even ask for a postoffice or DHL or FedX.

My question is also general but also specific for Istanbul since I'm here right now. How do people send valuable things back home? It's also a plus point if they have a pick-up service (e.g hotel or apartment).

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14280/ship-items-back-home-while-traveling

Comment: Are you staying at a hotel?

Comment: I'm staying at an apartment. I'm gonna be here for quite a while.

Comment: I would start by calling the company that makes the phone. They probably won't allow you to get it fixed in Turkey, but it's worth asking.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about international shipping.

Comment: How is your phone "Broken"?  If you've put a Tuskish SIM in it, and haven't paid the government to have the phone registered in Turkey, then you've probably been added to the government blacklist.

Comment: It's not the problem with the registration. It's about the software. It was hanging on the boot screen.

Comment: Istanbul is so touristic that you should have no problem to find somebody speaking english. Hagia Sophia or Taksim square would be the best places to search. Or order a tea at Café Pierre Loti and sympathize with the waiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These should solve your problem:

[List of DHL locations in Istanbul](http://www.dhl.com.tr/en/express/shipping/find_dhl_locations.html)

[List of UPS locations in Istanbul](http://www.ups.com/content/tr/en/contact)

[Map of post office locations in Istanbul](http://enyakinptt.ptt.gov.tr/)

DHL and UPS can pick up your package from your apartment. Call the number listed in the links above to arrange a pick up.